# Flink integration test(s) with Testcontainers

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, testcontainers

I have a simple `Apache Flink` job that looks very much like this:

```java
public final class Application {
  public static void main(final String... args) throws Exception {
    final var env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    final var executionConfig = env.getConfig();
    final var params = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);
    executionConfig.setGlobalJobParameters(params);
    executionConfig.setParallelism(params.getInt("application.parallelism"));

    final var source = KafkaSource.<CustomKafkaMessage>builder()
        .setBootstrapServers(params.get("application.kafka.bootstrap-servers"))
        .setGroupId(config.get("application.kafka.consumer.group-id"))
        // .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.committedOffsets(OffsetResetStrategy.EARLIEST))
        .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest())
        .setTopics(config.getString("application.kafka.listener.topics"))
        .setValueOnlyDeserializer(new MessageDeserializationSchema())
        .build();

    env.fromSource(source, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "custom.kafka-source")
        .uid("custom.kafka-source")
        .rebalance()
        .flatMap(new CustomFlatMapFunction())
        .uid("custom.flatmap-function")
        .filter(new CustomFilterFunction())
        .uid("custom.filter-function")
        .addSink(new CustomDiscardSink()) // Will be a Kafka sink in the future
        .uid("custom.discard-sink");

    env.execute(config.get("application.job-name"));
  }
}
```

Problem is that I would like to provide an integration test for the entire application — sort of like an end-to-end (set of) test(s) for the entire job. I'm using `Testcontainers`, but I'm not really sure how to move forward with this. For instance, this is how the test looks like (for now):

```java
@Testcontainers
final class ApplicationTest {
  private static final DockerImageName DOCKER_IMAGE = DockerImageName.parse("confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.0.1");

  @Container
  private static final KafkaContainer KAFKA_CONTAINER = new KafkaContainer(DOCKER_IMAGE);

  @ClassRule // How come this work in JUnit Jupiter? :/
  public static MiniClusterResource cluster;

  @BeforeAll
  static void init() {
    KAFKA_CONTAINER.start();
    // ...probably need to wait and create the topic(s) as well
    final var config = new MiniClusterResourceConfiguration.Builder().setNumberSlotsPerTaskManager(2)
        .setNumberTaskManagers(1)
        .build();
    cluster = new MiniClusterResource(config);
  }

  @Test
  void main() throws Exception {
    // new Application(); // ...what's next?
  }
}
```

I'm not sure how to implement what's required to trigger the job as-is from that point on. Basically, I would like to execute what was defined before, without (almost) any modifications — I've seen plenty of examples that practically build the entire job again, so that's not an option.

Can somebody provide any pointers here?

> `MessageDeserializationSchema` is unbounded, so `isEndOfStream` returns `false`. Not sure if that's an impediment.

Comment: Can you formulate in a BDD-style fashion what you want to test? This would help with suggestions on how you can get started. It does not seem like something Testcontainers specific to me.

Comment: I want to test what the job is _actually doing_. Basically, for this specific case, if I provide `X` valid input messages, I should see all of them published by the Kafka sink, with the correct modifications applied. It's really not `Tescontainers`-specific, but they are quite handy when executing these type of tests within JUnit itself, rather than properly running the job in a given environment and using some sort of automated process to achieve the same.

Comment: @x80486 did you manage to get it working? I'm struggling with stopping the flink job.

Comment: Not yet. For the time being I'm just doing a typical functional testing: run the job and have a series of processes that interact with the same — the runner is not `JUnit`, but `Gauge`. Would like to have those integration tests as well at some point run via `JUnit`.

Answer (score 2):

In order to make the pipeline more testable, I suggest you create a method on your `Application` class that takes a source and a sink as parameters, and creates and executes the pipeline, using those connectors.

In your tests you can call that method with special sources and sinks that you use for testing. In particular, you will want to use a `KafkaSource` that uses `.setBounded(...)` in the tests so that it cleanly handles just the range of data intended for the test(s).

The solutions and tests for the Apache Flink training exercises are organized along these lines; for example, see [RideCleansingSolution.java](https://github.com/apache/flink-training/blob/master/ride-cleansing/src/solution/java/org/apache/flink/training/solutions/ridecleansing/RideCleansingSolution.java) and [RideCleansingIntegrationTest.java](https://github.com/apache/flink-training/blob/master/ride-cleansing/src/test/java/org/apache/flink/training/exercises/ridecleansing/RideCleansingIntegrationTest.java). These examples don't use kafka or test containers, but hopefully they'll still be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you instrument your application as an opaque-box test by interacting with it through its public API. This can be done either as an out-process test (e.g. by running your application in a container as well, using Testcontainers) are as an in-process test (by creating your `Application` and calling its `main()` method).

Now in your comments you explained, that you want to check for the side-effects of interacting with your application (Kafka messages being published). To check this, connect to the `KafkaContainer` with your own `KafkaConsumer` from within the test and use a library such as [Awaitiliy](https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility) to wait until the messages have been received.